# (DEBIAN) Weird error when building Python from source

Tags: python, python-3.x, debian

After running `make` I am getting this weird error or something more like an error

```
Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-missing-field-initializers -Werror=implicit-function-declaration -fvisibility=hidden  -I./Include/internal  -I. -I./Include    -DPy_BUILD_CORE -o Objects/descrobject.o Objects/descrobject.c
^Cmake: *** [Makefile:1803: Objects/descrobject.o] Interrupt
```

Any Idea Why??

Comment: Did you… interrupt it with `^C`?